# Is P(C|A,B) equal to P(C|B,A)?

Tags: probability, markov-chains

My question is if P(C|A,B) is equal to P(C|B,A)?  In other words, does the order of the second component of the conditional probability matter?

Does it make any difference if the question is asked in the context of something like markov-chains, where we know that the order matters?

Comment: The are equal by definition since $P(C \mid A, B)$ _signifies by definition_ $P(C \mid A \cap B)$ and $A \cap B = B \cap A.$

Comment: @WilliamM. How do we know that the comma means an intersection of A and B?

Comment: That is a good question, it should be specified by the author. However, _if the author use the comma to mean something else_ then that author is using notation that is completely different from the most common standard.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are both equal as $ P(C|A, B) = \frac{P(A, B, C)}{P(A, B)} $ and $ P(C| B, A) = \frac{P(A, B, C)}{P(B, A)} $ from the definition of the conditional probability. Since $ P(A, B) = P(B, A) $, both expressions are equal.

In Markov contexts or other chain/graph structures where random variables are connected by their dependencies, you might come across the notations as $ P(x_i | x_{i-1}, x_{i-2}, ..., x_{i-n}) $, which is not different than $ P(x_i | x_{i-n}, ..., x_{i-2}, x_{i-1}) $, or any other random order. The reason why they are written in order is for notational clarity.

Specifically for Markov Chains, random variables only depend on the previous random variable in the chain, i.e. $ P(x_i|x_{i-1}) = P(x_{i} | x_{i-1}, x_{i-2}, ..., x_{i-n}) $.